# What are some Multivariate Imputation by Chained Regression (MICE) diagnostic plots?

Tags: data-visualization, missing-data, multiple-imputation, mice

The mice package [says](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/index.html), *"Many diagnostic plots are implemented to inspect the quality of the imputations."*

What are those plots?  Which are useful?  How do you use them?

Comment: If you're only asking what plots are implemented in this particular R package, this question is likely off-topic. Are you asking what plots *in general* (in any language) are used to assess imputed data?  If not, have you considered just reading though the plots listed in the package [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/mice.pdf) (eg, `bwplot.mads`, `bwplot.mids`, `densityplot.mids`, `fluxplot`, `md.pairs`, `md.patterns`, `plot.mids`, `stripplot.mids`, `xyplot.mids`, `xyplot.mads`)?

Comment: The package [vignette](https://www.gerkovink.com/miceVignettes/Missingness_inspection/Missingness_inspection.html) on inspecting the imputations and missingness might also be valuable.

Comment: Both of these comments are useful. Thank you. However, neither is an answer at the level I was hoping, i.e. a paragraph or so about which plots are useful and why. I don't see that in the docs or vignette. Rather, I just see all the details (long discussion of many plots). Also useful, but different.